# "Instruments cannot be opened because of a problem" (xcode4)

Tags: macos, xcode4, instruments

I'm trying to profile an app using Instruments, but every time I try to run I get a generic error message saying "Instruments cannot be opened because of a problem".  The exact same thing happens if I try to start Instruments manually outside of XCode.

If I try starting Instruments from the command-line, I get the following error details:

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found:
>   _CSSymbolicatorCreateWithMachKernel   Referenced from:
>   /Developer/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/../../../../Library/PrivateFrameworks//InstrumentsPlugIn.framework/Versions/A/InstrumentsPlugIn
>   Expected in:
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CoreSymbolication
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: _CSSymbolicatorCreateWithMachKernel
>   Referenced from:
>   /Developer/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/../../../../Library/PrivateFrameworks//InstrumentsPlugIn.framework/Versions/A/InstrumentsPlugIn
>   Expected in:
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CoreSymbolication

I just installed all of the available software updates, and it made no difference.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Your CoreSymbolication.framework seems to be too old.  An XCode reinstall might fix it.

Comment: Yes, that is certainly a popular suggestion for fixing this issue.  But that seems like a ridiculous overexpenditure of time/effort to fix an outdated/corrupt framework.  Is there no simpler solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a workaround that is a bit simpler than reinstalling all of XCode.  Basically I got another developer with a working copy of XCode/Instruments to send me a copy of their `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSymbolication.framework` file/folder.

Then I moved my local copy of `CoreSymbolication.framework` out of the way and dropped their version in.

After that everything works correctly.  And it's quite a bit faster than uninstalling and reinstalling XCode.